# ESLint rule forbidding Object Literals in JSX

Tags: reactjs, eslint, lint

[This article](https://marmelab.com/blog/2017/02/06/react-is-slow-react-is-fast.html) says: **Beware of Object Literals in JSX**

> Once your components become more “pure”, you start detecting bad
>   patterns that lead to useless rerenders. The most common is the usage
>   of object literals in JSX, which I like to call “The infamous {{”. Let
>   me give you an example:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import MyTableComponent from './MyTableComponent';

const Datagrid = (props) => (
     <MyTableComponent style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
         ...
     </MyTableComponent> 
 )
```

> The style prop of the  component gets a new value every time the  component is
>   rendered. So even if  is pure, it will be rendered
>   every time  is rendered. In fact, each time you pass an
>   object literal as prop to a child component, you break purity. The
>   solution is simple:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import MyTableComponent from  './MyTableComponent';

const tableStyle = { marginTop: 10 }; 

const Datagrid = (props) => (
     <MyTableComponent style={tableStyle}>
         ...
     </MyTableComponent> 
)
```

> This looks very basic, but I’ve seen this mistake so many times that I’ve > developed a sense for detecting the
>   infamous {{ in JSX. I routinely replace it with constants.

So my question is, is there any rule preventing using object literals in jsx?

I'm trying to find one, but no results yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**

I've found this plugin https://github.com/cvazac/eslint-plugin-react-perf in [one comment](https://medium.com/@cvazac/fantastic-write-up-on-an-important-subject-ac915de3b671) below this article: [React.js pure render performance anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@esamatti/react-js-pure-render-performance-anti-pattern-fb88c101332f).

This plugin offers rules below:

- `react-perf/jsx-no-new-object-as-prop`: Prevent {...} as JSX prop value
- `react-perf/jsx-no-new-array-as-prop`: Prevent [...] as JSX prop value
- `react-perf/jsx-no-new-function-as-prop`: Prevent function as JSX prop value
- `react-perf/jsx-no-jsx-as-prop`: Prevent JSX as JSX prop value

I think that this is exactly what you need.

---

Based on my quick look at https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react, I could not find any rule related to this issue. I think it's a good time for a pull request!

Right now you can use `jsx-no-bind` rule which checks for extra functions created on each `render` so thanks to this rule you can also prevent extra renders in your components.

https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

Comment: For future reference, I think this is the latest relevant PR in eslint-plugin-react: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/pull/3037